# Is it possible to persist the contents of a CALayer between drawInContext calls?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

Are there any built in abilities to maintain the contents of a CALayer between drawLayer:inContext: calls? Right now I am copying the layer to a buffer and redrawing an image from the buffer every time I called back in drawLayer:inContext: but I'm wondering if CALayer has a way to do this automatically...

Comment: Do you mean that when you tell a layer to drawincontext it loses it loses the value of its contents property?

Comment: @JustinMeiners Yes that is correct, it always starts from scratch

Comment: hmm I don't know then. that sounds like very strange behavior, once I set my layer.contents to a CGImage it never loses its pointer..

Comment: @JustinMeiners Sorry should have been more specific. I am not actually using layer.contents, I'm just doing a bunch of CG* drawing calls in the drawLayer:inContext: method in my UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so.  The 'drawInContext' will clear the underlying buffer so that you can draw to it.  However, if you forego the `drawInContext` or `drawRect` methods, you can set your layer.contents to a CGImage and that will be retained.

I personally do this for almost all of my routines.  I overwrite `- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame` to check to see if the frame size has changed.  If it has changed I redraw the image using my normal drawing routines but into the context: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, _opaque, 0);`.  I can then grab that image and set it to the imageCache: `cachedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`.  Then I set the layer.Contents to the CGImage.  I use this to help cache my drawings, especially on the new iPad which is slow on many drawing routines the iPad 2 doesn't even blink on.

Other advantages to this method: You can share cached images between views if you set up a separate, shared cache.  This can really help your memory footprint if you manage your cache well. (Tip: I use NSStringFromCGSize as a dictionary key for shared images).  Also, you can actually spin off your drawing routines on a different thread, and then set your layer contents when it's done. This prevents your drawing routines from blocking the main thread (the current image may be stretched in this case though until the new image is set).

Comment: Have you ever used CGLayerRef? Thanks for the response too.

Comment: No sorry, haven't really needed to.  I've pretty much stuck with the CALayer associated with the view.  However, when managing multiple layers I imagine you can pretty much do the same thing.  The conditions for initiating a re-draw might be a little more complex but I think the general idea should hold.  Using CGLayerRef might be more difficult, though, because you can't really overwrite functions/methods like you could by subclassing CALayer or using KVO.