# Animated pie chart that can animate in both directions

Tags: ios7, uiview, core-animation, calayer, blending

I am trying to build an animated pie chart that can animate the pie in both directions depending on whether the value of its `progress` increases or decreases. I've started with sample code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197239/animated-cashapelayer-pie/9150991#9150991) and made some adjustments as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597797/non-animatable-properties-in-subclasses-of-calayer).

The trouble is that the back-animation is not yet quite working. It only partially clears the pie. I am not quite sure whether this is due to me using animations incorrectly or calculating coordinates incorrectly, for if I insert `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor.CGColor);` into the first `if` branch and change blend mode to `kCGBlendModeNormal` also there the result is similarly off.

So here is my current code (excerpt from `PieLayer.m`) -- who can suggest improvements?

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    PieView *pieView = self.delegate;
    NSAssert(pieView != nil, nil);

    CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 1, 1);

    CGFloat radius = MIN(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(radius, CGRectGetMidY(rect));

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.clearColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, pieView.circumferenceTintColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);

    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rect);

    CGFloat startAngle   = -M_PI / 2;
    CGFloat endAngle     = self.progress     * 2 * M_PI + startAngle;
    CGFloat lastEndAngle = self.lastProgress * 2 * M_PI + startAngle;

    if (self.lastProgress > self.progress) {
        NSLog(@"clear sector between progress=%f and lastProgress=%f", self.progress, self.lastProgress);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y);
        CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius, endAngle, lastEndAngle, 0);
        CGContextClosePath(context);

        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
        CGContextFillPath(context);
    }

    if (self.progress > 0) {
        NSLog(@"draw sector to progress=%f (lastProgress=%f)", self.progress, self.lastProgress);

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, pieView.sectorTintColor.CGColor);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y);
        CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
        CGContextClosePath(context);

        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
        CGContextFillPath(context);
    }

    ((PieLayer *)self.modelLayer).lastProgress = self.progress;

    [super drawInContext:context];
}
```

Comment: The code in the first question you linked works fine in both directions, for me, event with `clearColor` as background. It doesn't work only when the foreground is clear, but that doesn't seem the case in your code. See [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B866aQXCBWHJTVhXREZ5SXNJOTQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: @PietroSaccardi You're right. I also see that it is working now in a stand-alone example. I must have an error in integrating the linked code elsewhere ...

Comment: @PietroSaccardi Strange, but if I place the `DZRoundProgressViewLayer` one level further down in my view hierarchy (with an empty `UIView` as superview), then it starts to work in both directions. (With `CGColorRef backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor;`) If you want to post your comment as an answer, I shall accept it since it led to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the answer you posted ([animated CAShapeLayer pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197239/animated-cashapelayer-pie/9150991#9150991)) works fine in both directions for me, even using `clearColor`: see [this video](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B866aQXCBWHJTVhXREZ5SXNJOTQ/edit).
The only situation in which `clearColor` does not produce a correct behavior is when the background color is solid and the foreground is clear: in that case a change in the blending mode is required, as you pointed out in your code.

I tried with these three configuration, and in all the cases the layer was responding correctly to `-setProgress:`.

- `DZRoundProgressView` as subview of the main `UIView`;
- Class of main view set to `DZRoundProgressView`;
- `DZRoundProgressView` as sublayer of the main `UIView`;

Moreover, it is unlikely that the content of a layer in the previous frame is still visible at the next draw call: apparently, the default behavior of `-drawInContext:` is to clear the context before execution, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11248120/1749822) says.
If you are not working with the `contents` property of the layer, and you are not hacking the drawing pipe, then there could be something wrong with the value of `self.progress`; perhaps some issue with presentation layer and model layer, or in the implementation of the property.

Indeed this doesn't solve your problem, since I couldn't reproduce it or isolate it, but should allow you to work around it.

Comment: +1 You're are also right about solving vs. work-around.